# Testing with fiveam

Tags: testing, common-lisp, fiveam

I can't figure out how to test a function with `fiveam`.  I setup a project using `cl-project`.  My project name is `my-projects/proj1`:

```
~/quicklisp% tree local-projects 
local-projects
├── dtrace
│   ├── dtrace.asd
│   └── dtrace.lisp
├── my-projects
│   └── proj1
│       ├── #proj1.asd#
│       ├── README.markdown
│       ├── README.org
│       ├── proj1.asd
│       ├── proj1.asd~
│       ├── src
│       │   ├── main.fasl
│       │   ├── main.lisp
│       │   └── main.lisp~
│       └── tests
│           ├── main.fasl
│           ├── main.lisp
│           └── main.lisp~
└── system-index.txt
```

And:

```
~/quicklisp/local-projects% cat system-index.txt 
dtrace/dtrace.asd
my-projects/proj1/proj1.asd
```

Here is `proj1/proj1.asd`:

```
(defsystem "proj1"
  :version "0.0.1"
  :author "7stud"
  :license "any"
  :depends-on ()
  :components ((:module "src"
                :components
                ((:file "main"))))
  :description ""
  :in-order-to ((test-op (test-op "proj1/tests"))))

(defsystem "proj1/tests"
  :author "7stud"
  :license "any"
  :depends-on ("proj1"
               "fiveam")
  :components ((:module "tests"
                :components
                ((:file "main"))))
  :description "Test system for proj1"
  :perform (test-op (op c) (symbol-call :fiveam '#:run! :proj1)))
```

`proj1/src/main.lisp`:

```
(defpackage proj1
  (:use :cl))
(in-package :proj1)

;; blah blah blah.

(defun anyoddp (number-list)
  (cond ((null number-list) nil)
        ((oddp (first number-list)) t)
        (t (anyoddp (rest number-list)))))
```

`proj1/tests/main.lisp`:

```
(defpackage proj1/tests/main
  (:use :cl
        :proj1
        :fiveam))
(in-package :proj1/tests/main)

;; Note: To run this test file, execute `(asdf:test-system :proj1)' in your Lisp.

;; (deftest test-target-1
;;   (testing "should (= 1 1) to be true"
;;            (ok (= 1 1))))

(def-suite master-suite
  :description "Test my system.")

(def-suite anyoddp-tests
  :description "Test anyoddp"
  :in master-suite)

(in-suite anyoddp-tests)

(test simple-maths
  (is (= 3 (+ 1 1))))

(test anyoddp-with-odds
  (let ((result (anyoddp '(1 3 4))))
    (is (equal result t))
    "True expected but got ~a" result))
```

I've tried every permutation of commands that I've read about in an attempt to test my proj1 "system", and I either get an error or `Didn't run anything...huh?`.   Here's my latest attempt:

```
CL-USER> (ql:quickload "fiveam")
To load "fiveam":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    fiveam
; Loading "fiveam"

("fiveam")
CL-USER> (asdf:load-system "proj1")
T
CL-USER> (asdf:test-system :proj1)
; compiling file "/Users/7stud/quicklisp/local-projects/my-projects/proj1/tests/main.lisp" (written 20 MAR 2024 10:04:40 AM):

; wrote /Users/7stud/.cache/common-lisp/sbcl-2.4.0-macosx-arm64/Users/7stud/quicklisp/local-projects/my-projects/proj1/tests/main-tmpUSHT8RIL.fasl
; compilation finished in 0:00:00.004
 Didn't run anything...huh?; in: ALEXANDRIA:NAMED-LAMBDA PROJ1/TESTS/MAIN::%TEST-ANYODDP-WITH-ODDS
;     (PROJ1/TESTS/MAIN::ANYODDP '(1 3 4))
; 
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   undefined function: PROJ1/TESTS/MAIN::ANYODDP
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   Undefined function:
;     PROJ1/TESTS/MAIN::ANYODDP
;   caught 1 STYLE-WARNING condition
T
CL-USER>
```

Why am I getting

> undefined function: PROJ1/TESTS/MAIN::ANYODDP

???  At the top of `proj1/tests/main.lisp` it says:

```
(defpackage proj1/tests/main
  (:use :cl
        :proj1
        :fiveam))
```

Isn't `use :proj1` supposed to let me call the functions defined in proj1 without the package name? Okay, here is `proj1/tests/main.lisp` with the package name added to the function name `anyoddp`:

```
(defpackage proj1/tests/main
  (:use :cl
        :proj1
        :fiveam))
(in-package :proj1/tests/main)

(def-suite master-suite
  :description "Test my system.")

(def-suite anyoddp-tests
  :description "Test anyoddp"
  :in master-suite)

(in-suite anyoddp-tests)

(test simple-maths
  (is (= 3 (+ 1 1))))

(test anyoddp-with-odds
  (let ((result (proj1::anyoddp '(1 3 4))))   ;; **CHANGE HERE**
    (is (equal result t))
    "True expected but got ~a" result))
```

Then:

```
CL-USER> (ql:quickload "fiveam")
To load "fiveam":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    fiveam
; Loading "fiveam"

("fiveam")
CL-USER> (asdf:load-system "proj1")
T
CL-USER> (asdf:test-system :proj1)
; compiling file "/Users/7stud/quicklisp/local-projects/my-projects/proj1/tests/main.lisp" (written 20 MAR 2024 10:33:11 AM):

; wrote /Users/7stud/.cache/common-lisp/sbcl-2.4.0-macosx-arm64/Users/7stud/quicklisp/local-projects/my-projects/proj1/tests/main-tmp7YCPD44Y.fasl
; compilation finished in 0:00:00.004
 Didn't run anything...huh?
T
CL-USER>
```

I'm also wondering if there is a way to use `fiveam` to test a function in a file that is not in a project.  Suppose I have this file:

```
;;  a.lisp

(defun anyoddp (number-list)
  (cond ((null number-list) nil)
        ((oddp (first number-list)) t)
        (t (anyoddp (rest number-list)))))
```

How can I add some tests to `a.lisp`, then run those tests?

Comment: The package problem is because you did not ever export anything from the `proj1` package.

Comment: Using a package does not mean "all its symbols are accessible". It means "all its **exported** symbols are accessible"

Comment: Does calling `run!` on the `'master-suite` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some progress running tests in a project.  I was able to execute my tests with the following code:

`proj1/src/main.lisp`:

```
(defpackage proj1
  (:use :cl)
  (:export :anyoddp))

(in-package :proj1)

;; blah blah blah.n

(defun anyoddp (number-list)
  (cond
    ((null number-list) nil)
    ((oddp (first number-list)) t)
    (t (anyoddp (rest number-list)))))
```

`proj1/tests/main.lisp`:

```
(defpackage proj1/tests/main
  (:use :cl
        :proj1
        :fiveam)
  (:export #:test-proj1))
(in-package :proj1/tests/main)

(defun test-proj1 ()
  (run! 'master-suite))

(def-suite master-suite
  :description "Test my system.")
(in-suite master-suite)

(test simple-maths
  (is (= 3 (+ 1 1))))


(def-suite anyoddp-tests
  :description "Test anyoddp"
  :in master-suite)
(in-suite anyoddp-tests)

(test anyoddp-with-odds
  (let ((result (anyoddp '(1 3 4))))   
    (is (equal result t))
    "True expected but got ~a" result))

(test anyoddp-with-evens
  (let ((result (anyoddp '(2 4 6))))
    (is (equal result nil))
    "Nil expected but got ~a" result))
```

Then in slime:

```
CL-USER> (ql:quickload 'proj1/tests)
; Evaluation aborted on #<QUICKLISP-CLIENT:SYSTEM-NOT-FOUND {7007278153}>.
CL-USER> (ql:register-local-projects)
NIL
CL-USER> (ql:quickload 'proj1/tests)
To load "proj1/tests":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    proj1/tests
; Loading "proj1/tests"

(PROJ1/TESTS)
CL-USER> (proj1/tests/main:test-proj1)

Running test suite MASTER-SUITE
 Running test SIMPLE-MATHS f
 Running test suite ANYODDP-TESTS
  Running test ANYODDP-WITH-ODDS .
  Running test ANYODDP-WITH-EVENS .
 Did 3 checks.
    Pass: 2 (66%)
    Skip: 0 ( 0%)
    Fail: 1 (33%)

 Failure Details:
 --------------------------------
 SIMPLE-MATHS in MASTER-SUITE []: 
      
(+ 1 1)

 evaluated to 

2

 which is not 

=

 to 

3


 --------------------------------

NIL
(#<IT.BESE.FIVEAM::TEST-FAILURE {700832DF43}>)
NIL
CL-USER>
```

I have no idea why I got this error:

```
CL-USER> (ql:quickload 'proj1/tests)
; Evaluation aborted on #<QUICKLISP-CLIENT:SYSTEM-NOT-FOUND {7007278153}>.
```

I, or rather `cl-project`, defined the "system" `proj1/tests` in the file `~/quicklisp/local-projects/my-projects/proj1/proj1.asd`:

```
(defsystem "proj1"
  :version "0.0.1"
  :author "7stud"
  :license "any"
  :depends-on ()
  :components ((:module "src"
                :components
                ((:file "main"))))
  :description "Some functions"
  :in-order-to ((test-op (test-op "proj1/tests"))))

(defsystem "proj1/tests"
  :author ""
  :license ""
  :depends-on ("proj1"
               "fiveam")
  :components ((:module "tests"
                :components
                ((:file "main"))))
  :description "Test system for proj1"
  :perform (test-op (op c) (symbol-call :fiveam '#:run!)))
```

In any case, the command:

```
(ql:register-local-projects)
```

causes quickslip to look through the directories under `~/quicklisp/local-projects` and write the paths to all the .asd files it finds into `~/quicklisp/local-projects/system-index.txt`.  After I evaluated that command, then `(ql:quickload 'proj1/tests)` was successful.

Essentially, I loaded a system, then I used a package name that was defined somewhere in the system to call a function defined in that package:

```
(proj1/tests/main:test-proj1)
 |              | |        |
 +-------+------+ +---+----+
         |            |
      package      function 
       name          name
```

And, here are the changes I made to `proj1.asd` to integrate with `asdf`:

```
(defsystem "proj1"
  :version "0.0.1"
  :author "7stud"
  :license "any"
  :depends-on ()
  :components ((:module "src"
                :components
                ((:file "main"))))
  :description "Some functions"
  :in-order-to ((test-op (test-op "proj1/tests"))))

(defsystem "proj1/tests"
  :author ""
  :license ""
  :depends-on ("proj1"
               "fiveam")
  :components ((:module "tests"
                :components
                ((:file "main"))))
  :description "Test system for proj1"
  :perform (test-op (o s)
       (symbol-call :fiveam '#:run!
          (find-symbol* '#:master-suite
                        :proj1/tests/main))))
```

Then:

```
CL-USER> (ql:quickload 'proj1/tests)
To load "proj1/tests":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    proj1/tests
; Loading "proj1/tests"
[package proj1]...................................
[package proj1/tests/main]
(PROJ1/TESTS)
CL-USER> (asdf:test-system 'proj1/tests)

Running test suite MASTER-SUITE
 Running test SIMPLE-MATHS f
 Running test suite ANYODDP-TESTS
  Running test ANYODDP-WITH-ODDS .
  Running test ANYODDP-WITH-EVENS .
 Did 3 checks.
    Pass: 2 (66%)
    Skip: 0 ( 0%)
    Fail: 1 (33%)

 Failure Details:
 --------------------------------
 SIMPLE-MATHS in MASTER-SUITE []: 
      
(+ 1 1)

 evaluated to 

2

 which is not 

=

 to 

3


 --------------------------------

T
```

And:

```
CL-USER> (asdf:test-system 'proj1)

Running test suite MASTER-SUITE
 Running test SIMPLE-MATHS f
 Running test suite ANYODDP-TESTS
  Running test ANYODDP-WITH-ODDS .
  Running test ANYODDP-WITH-EVENS .
 Did 3 checks.
    Pass: 2 (66%)
    Skip: 0 ( 0%)
    Fail: 1 (33%)

 Failure Details:
 --------------------------------
 SIMPLE-MATHS in MASTER-SUITE []: 
      
(+ 1 1)

 evaluated to 

2

 which is not 

=

 to 

3


 --------------------------------

T
CL-USER>
```

Whenever I made changes to the files in `~/quicklisp/local-projects/my-projects/proj1/`, I usually tried to execute:

```
CL-USER> (ql:quickload 'proj1)
```

or

```
CL-USER> (ql:quickload 'proj1/tests)
```

in the slime repl.  I found that the slime repl would often get out of sync with the current files in `proj1`, which would cause errors.

As far as I can figure out, this line:

```
  :perform (test-op (o s)
       (symbol-call :fiveam '#:run!
          (find-symbol* '#:master-suite
                        :proj1/tests/main))))
```

has to use some trickery because it is read before the packages/functions in `proj1` are created. `symbol-call` is in the uiop package, and it is used to specify a function call that is read before the package containing the function definition exists.  You specify the package name, the function name, and the args.  In `symbol-call` above, the package name is `:fiveam`, the function name is `'#:run!` and the arg for the function is whatever is returned by:

```
(find-symbol* '#:master-suite :proj1/tests/main)
```

`find-symbol*` is a function in the `uiop` package which comes with `asdf` which comes with `sbcl`, which is the lisp implementation I'm using.  `find-symbol*` takes a symbol and a package name as arguments and is used when the package isn't present.

The result is, I am specifying a function call something like:

```
(fiveam:run! proj1/tests/main:master_suite)
```

But, instead of dealing with all that crazy syntax, I found I can do this:

```
 :perform (test-op (o s)
       (symbol-call :proj1/tests/main :test-proj1)))
```

`test-proj1` is this function:

```
(defun test-proj1 ()
  (run! 'master-suite))
```

which is defined in the package `proj1/tests/main`, which is defined in the file `.../proj1/test/main.lisp`.  Then I only needed to export the function `test-proj1`:

`...proj1/tests/main.lisp`:

```
(defpackage proj1/tests/main
  (:use :cl
        :proj1
        :fiveam)
  (:export #:test-proj1))
(in-package :proj1/tests/main)

(defun test-proj1 ()
  (run! 'master-suite))
```

I found nothing about what `test-op (o s)` does.

Resources:

1. ASDF manual: [test-op](https://asdf.common-lisp.dev/asdf.html#test_002dop)
2. [Tutorial: Working with FiveAM](https://turtleware.eu/posts/Tutorial-Working-with-FiveAM.html)

Comment: Too much to read.
But quicklist/asdf (via quickload/load-system) will only look at the root "quicklisp/local-projects" for projects. IIRC you can tell ASDF to look elsewhere also but you'd need to have a look at the ASDF documentation.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm also wondering if there is a way to use fiveam to test a function in a file that is not in a project.

Well you can define tests anywhere and run them by the test suite or the test name.

You can also put them behind a feature flag.

First possibility, a test for the developer to check manually:

```lisp
#+(or)
;; or your own marker in *features*.
(equal t (anyoddp '(1 2 3)))
```

Just C-c C-c on it.

We can add fiveam tests.

```lisp
(use-package :fiveam)

(def-suite oddtest)

(in-suite oddtest)

(test simple-maths
  (is (= 2 (+ 1 2))))
```

and run one:

```
CL-USER> (in-package :proj1)
PROJ1> (run! 'SIMPLE-MATHS)
Running test suite ODDTEST
 Running test SIMPLE-MATHS f
 Did 1 check.
    Pass: 0 ( 0%)
    Skip: 0 ( 0%)
    Fail: 1 (100%)

 Failure Details:

[…]
```

Running the test suite:

```
PROJ1> (run! 'oddtest)
Running test suite ODDTEST
Running test suite ODDTEST
[…]
```

and we could place everything under a `#+5am` feature flag.

You can use a couple parameters to make writing/running tests more interactive.

### Running the test at compilation

```
  #+(or)
  (setf fiveam:*run-test-when-defined* t)
```

now C-c C-c runs the test on the REPL.

### Getting the debugger on a test failure

```
  #+(or)
  (setf fiveam:*on-failure* :debug)
```

now we get a debugger on a test failure.

Comment: *Just C-c C-c on it.* -- That doesn't do anything useful for me.  In slime, I see: `; processing (EQUAL T ...)`--just as I would if I typed C-c C-c on a function: `; processing (DEFUN ANYODDP ...)`

Comment: `CL-USER> (in-package :proj1)` -- There's no package `proj1` in your file.

Comment: *now C-c C-c runs the test on the REPL.* -- Not for me.

Comment: *Just C-c on it* OK, add an `assert` before the `equal`. Or, use C-x C-e (eval and see result) or send expression to the REPL (C-c C-j) to see T or NIL.

Comment: mmh… double check fiveam variables?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I got tests to run in a single file:

```
;; c.lisp

(defpackage my-list-functions
  (:use :cl
        :fiveam))
(in-package my-list-functions)

(defun anyoddp (alist)
  (cond ((null alist) nil)
        ((oddp (first alist)) t)
        (t (anyoddp (rest alist)))))

(def-suite master-suite
  :description "All tests")

(def-suite simple-tests
  :description "Some simple tests"
  :in master-suite)
(in-suite simple-tests)

(test test1
  (is (= 2 (+ 1 1))))

(test test2
      (is (= 3 (+ 4 3))))

(def-suite anyoddp-tests
  :description "Test anyoddp"
  :in master-suite)
(in-suite anyoddp-tests)

(test anyoddp-with-list-of-evens
  (is (equal (anyoddp '(2 4 6)) nil))
  (is (equal (anyoddp '(2)) nil))
  (is (equal (anyoddp '()) nil)))

(test anyoddp-with-list-containing-odds
  (is (equal (anyoddp '(2 3 4)) t))
  (is (equal (anyoddp '(2 3)) t))
  (is (equal (anyoddp '(1)) t)))
```

Here's what I tried:

```
C-x C-s   save c.lisp
C-c C-k   compile c.lisp

The name "FIVEAM" does not designate any package.
   [Condition of type PACKAGE-DOES-NOT-EXIST]
```

Then:

```
CL-USER> (ql:quickload "fiveam")
To load "fiveam":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    fiveam
; Loading "fiveam"

("fiveam")
CL-USER>
```

Then `C-c C-k` again in the c.lisp buffer. slime said:

```
; compiling file "/Users/7stud/lisp_programs/c.lisp" (written 20 MAR 2024 03:08:06 PM):

; wrote /Users/7stud/lisp_programs/c.fasl
; compilation finished in 0:00:00.009
```

Then:

```
CL-USER> (run! 'master-suite)
; in: RUN! 'MASTER-SUITE
;     (RUN! 'MASTER-SUITE)
; 
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   undefined function: COMMON-LISP-USER::RUN!
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   Undefined function:
;     RUN!
;   caught 1 STYLE-WARNING condition
; Evaluation aborted on #<UNDEFINED-FUNCTION RUN! {7005A44223}>.
CL-USER>
```

Then:

```
CL-USER> (fiveam:run! 'master-suite)
 Didn't run anything...huh?
T
NIL
NIL
CL-USER>
```

Then:

```
CL-USER> (in-package my-list-functions)
#<PACKAGE "MY-LIST-FUNCTIONS">

MY-LIST-FUNCTIONS> (run! 'master-suite)

Running test suite MASTER-SUITE
 Running test suite SIMPLE-TESTS
  Running test TEST1 .
  Running test TEST2 f
 Running test suite ANYODDP-TESTS
  Running test ANYODDP-WITH-LIST-OF-EVENS ...
  Running test ANYODDP-WITH-LIST-CONTAINING-ODDS ...
 Did 8 checks.
    Pass: 7 (87%)
    Skip: 0 ( 0%)
    Fail: 1 (12%)

 Failure Details:
 --------------------------------
 TEST2 in SIMPLE-TESTS []: 
      
(+ 4 3)

 evaluated to 

7

 which is not 

=

 to 

3


 --------------------------------

NIL
(#<IT.BESE.FIVEAM::TEST-FAILURE {7006ADD9F3}>)
NIL
MY-LIST-FUNCTIONS>
```

And:

```
MY-LIST-FUNCTIONS> (run! 'anyoddp-tests)

Running test suite ANYODDP-TESTS
 Running test ANYODDP-WITH-LIST-OF-EVENS ...
 Running test ANYODDP-WITH-LIST-CONTAINING-ODDS ...
 Did 6 checks.
    Pass: 6 (100%)
    Skip: 0 ( 0%)
    Fail: 0 ( 0%)

T
NIL
NIL
MY-LIST-FUNCTIONS>
```